# How to retrieve data from SWAPI in React

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

Need to do more than one fetch to SWAPI

I want to display the Characters' films and species info. I managed to make an initial fetch, that gives me the names and the urls for the species and films, but fail to understand how to makes these show as strings in my CardComponent

https://scrimba.com/c/cDrN9Tb  -> I duplicated my project in this scrimba. Please check it out.

App Component

```
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          films: [],
          species: '',
        }

      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/';

        fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(people => this.setState({ data: people.results }));

        }



      render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        return (
          <div className='App'>
              <NavBar />
              <Header />
              {
                data.length === 0
                ? <h3>Loading Cards...</h3>
                : <h3>Cards Count: {data.length}</h3>
              }
              <CardContainer data={data} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

---

Card Component

```
    const CardComponent = ({ name, species, films }) => {

      return (
        <div className='Card'>
          <h3>{ name }</h3>
          <h4 style={{fontStyle: 'italic'}}>The species.name value should be shown below... not the url</h4>
          <h4>{ species }</h4>
          <div>Featured in:
            <p style={{fontStyle: 'italic'}}>(movie titles should be show in the list below, not the urls...)</p>
              <ul>
                {films.map((film, i) => (
                  <li key={i}>
                    { film }
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

I'm just new at this and cant come up with the solution. Read all swapi-react related entries I could find, but still no luck in solving this. Please be patient with this tired brain =P

--EDIT---

[Species problem solved thanks to SakoBu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD4ep.png)

Comment: The data that is coming back is the url for the films... If you want to display the name of the films you would need to send another get request to that url, get the title and display that...

Comment: Could you please show me an example of how to so that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution... Change your Card Component to this and you will get the species showing up as you want...

```
import React from 'react';

export default class CardComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { species: '' };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.species[0])
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ species: json.name }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Card">
        <h3>Name: {this.props.name}</h3>
        <h4 style={{ fontStyle: 'italic', color: 'red' }}>
          The species.name value should be shown below... not the url
        </h4>
        <h4>Species: {this.state.species}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks! Got the species showing now! I had thought about doing it this way with the class component, but couldnt get my head around it. I feel I'm on the right track now! 

Tomorrow will try to tackle the films issue, which shouldnt be much different, I guess...

Cheers!